# In SQLite3, is there a way to continue a query after row-limiting?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a SQL query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM database WHERE column LIKE ? ORDER BY column LIMIT 128
```

I would like to be able to obtain, eg, rows 129-256 of the same table. Is there a way to do this with a SQLite query?

(I could redo the same query `LIMIT 256` and then skip the first 128 results before further processing, however, I feel like it would be better code to use a SQL query that simply returns the values I actually need to process.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add either an `OFFSET` clause or use two comma-separated values as the arguments of the LIMIT clause, as described in the [LIMIT clause section of SQLite's syntax reference](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#the_limit_clause).

In other words: `... LIMIT 128 OFFSET 128`, or `... LIMIT 128, 128`.

Note: in the `LIMIT a, b` form, `a` is the offset and `b` the limit.